# PerlUnit in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, perl, unit-testing, junit, eclipse-plugin

If we click on  Java perspective in Eclipse and right click on a Java project, we see “new” a JUnit file.On executing the test cases in JUnit we see red/green bar displaying failure/success of test cases.

I am trying to find a plugin that would add these two features :

- In the perl perspective (provided by EPIC) , right-click on a Perl
  project should list a new “t” file.
- On executing perl unit the status of test cases should be displayed
  using Reed/Green bar.

If there is no plugin is there a way we can do the same.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no EPIC plugin for this or even a more generic TAP-based test runner for Eclipse. Such a thing would be nice to have.

Rigging some sort of report on test success from a web page is pretty common. This can be done using a tool like [Test::Harness](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aHarness) which can be used to run your test or tests and return or output a report of how well your test run went.

From there, it's a matter of turning that into a red/green progress bar.

If you want to see the progress updated continuously during the test run, you'll have to run and parse the test files more directly as they run. All Perl tests output TAP format, which is a standard format with specs available here:

- http://testanything.org